# Oracle RightNow mock api for automation

Tags: rightnow-crm

I'm trying to do automation tests on functionality that is calling Oracle RightNow support service.

Does Oracle provide some kind of mock API that I can send requests to and get some responses as part of my automated tests?

thanks

Comment: Hello otto, have you tried to research something about this topic before asking a question on StackOverflow? If so, can you point possible answerers in the correct direction by telling them what have you tried and what are you missing? Also I would highly reccommend asking Oracle directly as they have quite a good support. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I used Customer Portal for creating mock servers, but I'm more of a beginner on Oracle Services. I'm trying to figure out if Oracle has something created for this in particular before I start implementing a mock server with something like JSON Server.

Comment: also asking Oracle directly is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

@otto Service Cloud does not provide a Mock API service.  However, each production instance comes with at least one test environment.  So, with an account that has profile permissions to access the Connect for REST APIs, you can use the test environment for your test API calls.  As long as the test environment and your production environment are on the same Service Cloud version, then the responses will have the same structure / schema from call-to-call.